# How to add gif to attachment in iPhone mail?

Tags: ios, email, attachment, gif

I add .jpg this way:

```
UIImage *sentPic = self.image;
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sentPic, 1);
[picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"pic.jpg"];
```

I change it to "image/gif".But it doesn't work fine. Th Gif is just a still image in the mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToGifFile];
[picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/gif" fileName:@"pic.gif"];
[imageData release];
```

This would add it as attachment, but I'm not sure if that's what you want, or you want to display the image inside the message?

Comment: Thank you. This works too:   NSData *imageDataGif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/gif.gif", NSHomeDirectory()]];
    [picker addAttachmentData:imageDataGif mimeType:@"image/GIF" fileName:@"GifDemo.gif"];

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried HTML code in your email like this:

```
NSString *emailBody = @"It is a gif email!";
emailBody = [EmailBody stringByAppendingString:@"<img src='http://xx.xx.pic.gif'>"];
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

The code I haven't tested, you can have a try. Tell us if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this. Works great:

```
NSString *pathForGif = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"<your file name>" ofType: @"gif"];

NSData *gifData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: pathForGif];

[mailController addAttachmentData:gifData mimeType:@"image/gif" fileName:@"EmailGIF.gif"];
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
```